# SFDX: Create User with Salesforce License in Scratch Org

Tags: profile, salesforcedx, licenses, user-record

I'm trying to create a user in a scratch org through SF CLI using `force:user:create` and a `user-def.json` file. Here is a sample body request according to [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_users_def_file.htm):

```
{
    "Username": "tester1@sfdx.org",
    "LastName": "Hobbs",
    "Email": "tester1@sfdx.org",
    "Alias": "tester1",
    "TimeZoneSidKey": "America/Denver",
    "LocaleSidKey": "en_US",
    "EmailEncodingKey": "UTF-8",
    "LanguageLocaleKey": "en_US",
    "profileName": "Standard Platform User",
    "permsets": ["Dreamhouse", "Cloudhouse"],
    "generatePassword": true
}
```

Nothing is mentioned in the doc how to select the user license. By default it seems that the user license is Salesforce Platform. So when I try to create a user with a custom profile(i.e.: Sales User) linked to a Salesforce license instead, I'm getting the following error :

```
ERROR:  There are no available user licenses for the user profile "Sales User".
```

Could someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: The license is based off of the profile. You've probably used up all your available licenses (check in the setup -> company info). I think you only get 2 (after the admin)

Comment: This: `<userLicense>Salesforce</userLicense>` is the line in the profile that determines which license the profile is for.

Comment: Actually in a way you were right, I'm limited to 5 user licenses in Enterprise Scratch Org. Originally I tried to create my users manually in the scratch org and I had some unknown error please contact Salesforce blabla. But it actually created the users anyway a few minutes after that. So when I tried from CLI, no more available licenses. Make sense. Thank u

Comment: Yeah, I had the exact same thing, errors on creating the user, but it still created them and then when I fixed the error I got an out of licenses error.